# Enumerate allocated objects

Tags: c++, memory, low-level-code

How do I enumerate all allocated objects (allocated by the new operator) (not only those which have their own memory mappings, but those which are on the heap, too?) in C++?

I need this to find memory leaks.

Platform: Linux, gcc, i386,AMD_K64 (better: Platform independent)

There may be no official way, but there may be a lean workaround.
For example, is there some internal variable you could access? Maybe a pointer to the list used for management of the heap?

Comment: [massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif)

Comment: What you're asking for is just the tires on the monster truck that leak detectors are. Why not use one of the numerous existing ones?

Comment: Because I want to build a motorbike :) it should provide the user with a lookup view, without putting much weight into the program, to discover what is happening on his own when the program fails. But right, now, I am actually trying out massif, of which I didn't know that it hijacks the malloc function (and I didn't know that exactly any new calls a malloc)

Answer (score 0):

You always can use valgrind to check for memory leaks. Either install it with your package manager or just download and compile from: http://valgrind.org/

If you compile your application in debug mode it can pinpoint down to the file/line where you have allocated resources that were not freed/deleted.

Comment: Wait! Quote: massif runs Programs 20x slower than normal. I can not regularly add this into my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **valgrind** it does exactly what you want (replaces malloc with it's own implementation) and counts allocations/releases

Comment: Theoretically, but it causes too much overhead. btw. there is no massif.h for reflective use of valgrind. Nice tool, but no way too add features in my program, such as "get pointer to the n'th instance of..."

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially two forms of memory lose

1. Memory that was allocated, but it is no longer referenced from any place... and so it will not be possible to delete it. This is a *proper leak*. In Linux, the main tool of choice is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Valgrind is a framework for multiple tools. The tool you would be after is [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck)....  This is a dynamic analysis tool that will report about leaks and other memory problems. This goes further than enumerating the memory allocated, but it also needs to check whether it is still referenced or not.
2. Memory that was allocated and it is still referenced, but somehow you've forgotten about it (e.g. vectors that grow endlessly because no-one never removes from them). This is where you need a tool for telling you the composition of all the memory you've allocated. Again valgrind can help you here. The tool this time is called [massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif)

I'm sure there are more tools out there. These are pretty popular.

In Solaris, I'd recommend libumem for leak tracking and analyzer in Sun's Studio for profiling and memory analysis.

Comment: I cannot use any of that. I cannot find a way to (access the internal massif recordings) from the observed process. Valgrind adds a huge new dependency, disturbs the program's identity, and may even introduce memory leaks on its own.